# In Javascript, How to display a number in a textbox for a particular option.

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

In JavaScript I need help appending values into a textbox. What happens is that with the relevant piece of code below, the user can add an "Option Type" from a table row into the textbox. For example if the user clicks on the "Add" button and within that row the Option Type is  "True or False", then I want it to display number 27 in the textbox, and if "Option Type" is "Yes or No" then display number 28 in the textbox. So I want it like below

```
Option Type             Number

True or False           27
Yes or No               28
```

My question is how can insert the numbers for the 2 option types into the textbox?

I tried this below for True or False but it did not work:

```
var myNumbers = {};

   myNumbers["True-False"] = "27";

   gridValues = myNumbers[gridValues];
```

Below is the true and false buttons:

```
<input name="answerTrueName"  id="answerTrue"   type="button"   value="True"    onclick="btnclick(this);"/>
<input name="answerFalseName" id="answerFalse"  type="button"   value="False"   onclick="btnclick(this);"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, it is suppose to be:

```
var myNumbers = {};

   myNumbers["True or False"] = "27";

   gridValues = myNumbers[gridValues];
```